# Merging rows with different variables

Tags: r

After using pivot_wider(), I have a data frame like this:

| country | year | variable 1 | variable 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2000 | 0.5 | NA |
| A | 2000 | NA | 68 |
| B | 2000 | NA | 55 |
| B | 2000 | 0.9 | NA |

What is the easiest way to make it like this:

| country | year | variable 1 | variable 2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2000 | 0.5 | 68 |
| B | 2000 | 0.9 | 55 |

Thank you

---

---

Before pivot_wider(), the data frame was like this:

| country | year | variables | values |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 2000 | variable 1 | 0.5 |
| A | 2000 | variable 2 | 68 |
| B | 2000 | variable 1 | 0.9 |
| B | 2000 | variable 2 | 55 |

Code:

```
data <- data %>% pivot_wider(names_from = variables, values_from = values)
```

Comment: Since that result is post-`pivot_longer`, that suggests the pivot was either done incorrectly or should not have been done in the first place. Please post the pre-pivot data and the code you used to get to this.

Comment: @r2evans sorry, I meant pivot_wider. Updated post

Comment: When I run your code on that new batch of data, I get your desired output.

Comment: My pivot_wider was wrong. Thank you!

Comment: See the answer below.  You have to specify id columns in argument `id_cols`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct way for pivot_wider

```
data <- data %>% pivot_wider(id_cols = c(country, year), names_from = variables, values_from = values)
```